# Attempt to access a global temporary table already in use

Tags: oracle, hibernate, global-temp-tables

I'm trying to insert data to a global temporary table in Oracle from my application using Hibernate session. This data will then be used by a DB procedure called from the same application.
The global temporary table was created with **on commit delete rows**

```
session.save();
session.save();
session.save();
session.flush();
```

However, I'm getting below error on **session.flush()** line

```
Hibernate: insert into GTT_CHG_DTLS (CAC_NUMBER, SKIP_CREDIT_CHECK, GTT_CHG_ID) values (?, ?, ?)

WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-7) SQL Error: 14450, SQLState: 72000

ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-7) ORA-14450: attempt to access a transactional temp table already in use

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3193)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3707)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1472)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-14450: attempt to access a transactional temp table already in use
```

Comment: Are you attempting to drop or truncate or alter the temporary table? If so, don't. They are not meant to be dropped and recreated, and there's no need to truncate as it will be empty at transaction start. If you do have to do some one-time DDL (which should not be done by code, or it isn't one-time), you would need to kill any session using it first.

Comment: @PaulW No DDL operations on the table. I’m just trying to insert some data in the table which will be used later by a database procedure to do some calculations within the same transaction.

Comment: Can you share the SQL - all any any of it, that is hitting this table?

Comment: Hibernate: insert into GTT_CHG_DTLS (CAC_NUMBER, SKIP_CREDIT_CHECK, GTT_CHG_ID) values (?, ?, ?)

Comment: Check to make sure you aren't in an autonomous transaction where you've already inserted rows outside the autonomous transaction. Check that hibernate isn't adding additional SQL. Get your DBA to perform 10046 trace so you can definitively finger the actual SQL that threw the error if you're not entirely sure what hibernate might be doing under the covers. A normal insert should not throw this error even if the table is being used by many other sessions.

Comment: Got it, but the error is throwing while executing session.flush() only

Comment: That is not an Oracle call. That's why I said you may need a 10046 trace to find out what the actual database call is that is throwing the error.